# Laravel 5.7 validation required_if null

Tags: php, laravel

I work with Laravel 5.7.

This is a contact form and i have different input fields and the `phone` or/and the `email` address must be given.
If this is not the case, an error message should appear.

Here is the html code from phone and email:

```
                 <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
                    @honeypot
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" class="form-control">
                        @if ( $errors->has('email') )
                            <div class="error-red">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</div>
                        @endif
                </div>

               <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <label for="phone">Mobile</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" class="form-control">
                        @if ( $errors->has('phone') )
                            <div class="error-red">{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</div>
                        @endif
               </div>
```

I tried this first but there is no error message:

```
        'firstName' => 'nullable',
        'lastName' => 'nullable',
        'email' => ['nullable', 'required_if:phone,=,null', 'email'],
        'phone' => ['nullable', 'required_if:email,=,null'],
```

Next I tried this (is the same without `=`) but it didn't work either:

```
        'firstName' => 'nullable',
        'lastName' => 'nullable',
        'email' => ['nullable', 'required_if:phone,null', 'email'],
        'phone' => ['nullable', 'required_if:email,null'],
```

Does anyone see a bug? I've done this a number of times and it has always worked so far.

Comment: Try `required_without:phone` and `required_without:email`

Comment: ohh nice! thats work! thanks!